# Connect a third-party api to a graphene and sqlalchemy api

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I have a Postgres database and on top of it, I've built a Graphql API using Graphene and SQLAlchemy. You can see some more details of the implementation in an earlier question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72579743/query-data-with-graphene-using-custom-filters)

Everything is working as expected but now I want to connect my API to the API of another system using a variable stored in my database. For example, I can query my API using a query like this:

```
query{dataset(datasetName:"MyDataset") {
        redName
    }
}
```

I then want to search my third-party API using the string value of `redName`. Ideally, I'd like this to take place in a resolver so ultimately my GraphQL API would return a JSON like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "dataset": {
      "datasetName": "MyDataset"
      "redData":{
                 "all": "the"
                 "data" "from"
                 "the External": "API"
                 }
    }
  }
}
```

The schema for the Postgres database is defined using SQLAlchemy classes but the third-party API returns a JSON. Can I define a class for the JSON that the external API returns? How do I search the external API by a value returned by my initial resolver?

Links to articles or other documentation on how to do this would also be helpful.

Comment: this redData resolver would be fetching data only from external API or it would be mixed of local and external data? For external only data, you can define graphene object type that would be feeded by JSON.

Comment: I'd prefer to present the local and external data as a single JSON. So the resolved would do one trip to the local database to retrieve the search term, then query the external api and then stich the two results together and present them as a single file. However, if I have to have a second query for the external api JSON, I could make that work.

Comment: Ok, tell what you does it mean for you `How do I search the external API by a value returned by my initial resolver?`? You would like to use `datasetName` value as an argument for external API? Using other resolvers as arguments could be tricky but you can probably get desired data within `redData` resolver, but you have to tell which resolver value you need.